# How to extract text from link @?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to extract some text from

```
@post.link
```

for ex. "http://test.com/c/849324"

I used this code to read the link after /c/

```
@v = @post.link.read(/c/)
```

but I get this error

```
undefined method `read' for
```

Maybe is not the correct method to use for this case

EDIT:
I want to get '849324' from "http://test.com/c/849324"

Comment: Are you trying to extract text from the page or break apart the URL?

Comment: break apart the URL >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `@post.link.split('/c/').last`

Answer (score 0):

> you can use regexp directly through string index.

```
first_group = string[/text(grp)/, 1] # get content of captured group
```

from: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#regular-expressions

---

Example using irb:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> URI("http://test.com/c/849324").path
=> "/c/849324"
irb(main):004:0> URI("http://test.com/c/849324").path[/^\/c\/(.*)/, 1]
=> "849324"
```

---

Answer:

```
URI("http://test.com/c/849324").path[/^\/c\/(.*)/, 1]
```

Comment: yeah, but the link is inside of @post.link

Comment: `URI(@post.link).path[/^\/c\/(.*)/, 1]`

Comment: If the URL doesn't change (e.g. for dev, staging and production environments) you could use: `@post.link[/^http:\/\/test\.com\/c\/(.*)/, 1]`